# rendering multipe html pages

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project and i need to use multiple html pages to interact with my code
like:
viewing index.html first:-

```
 path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
 self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

and then when i press the sign out button the program should view this  page:-

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'signOut.html')
 self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

the problem is that the program views the two pages together at one time and this is not what i want.

could you plz tell me how can I view them seperately

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')   
         self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class SignOutPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'signOut.html')   
         self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication( 
                                 [('/', MainPage), 
                                  ('/signout', SignOutPage)], 
                                 debug=True) 

def main(): 
    run_wsgi_app(application) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Your two pages will then be available at http://yourapp.appspot.com/ and http://yourapp.appspot.com/signout

This assumes that your app.yaml is mapping both urls to your .py file.